# Isight does not read Abaqus .cae files

Tags: abaqus

I would need to use Isight and Abaqus to run a parametric study. However, when I try to read the abaqus .cae file using Isight, nothing really happens, that means no variables are displayed in the Component Editor window (please, see the screenshot below). I searched online for this issue and I found many users having problems with .inp files but not with .cae files... my case is the opposite! Does any of you know how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem.

You need first to specify the Abaqus Command under Execution tab:

[image]

Please note that you might require a different Abaqus Command, for example:
C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abq2018hf4.bat input=test.inp job=test interactive

Click Apply and go to the Input tab. There, browse the .cae file and you should get the list of parameters:

[image]

Finally, make sure to select the correct file in the Output tab:

[image]

Should you still have problems reading the parameters from the .cae file, make sure they are specified in the model. For example, to make the cross section dimensions accessible by Isight, you first need to dimension them:

[image]